# Set base dir of PlayProject in sbt's project/Build.scala

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is it possible to change the base dir of a play project?

```
val web = PlayProject("web",).dependsOn(common)
```

the same way as I can change it in a standard sbt project

```
val common = Project(id = "common", base = file("common"))

val akka_service = Project(id = "service", base = file("service")).dependsOn(common)
```

The thing I want to accomplish is a directory structure like this

```
MyApp
     myWebApp
         app
             controllers
             views            
         conf
         public
     common
         src
             scala
     service
         src
             scala
     project
         Build.scala
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ([and described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794500/play-2-0-framework-multi-module-project)), the submodules have to be subfolders of the containing app folder, but your verson control system should allow you to include shared repos inside a project.

If you want to automatically reload the play application when a change in the common-library took place, make sure the subproject is a play project itself (only needs a /conf folder and /app for the sources)