# Setup IntelliJ project for two Play 2.0 apps and a shared entities repo?

Tags: git, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm hoping to start using IntelliJ for my two apps based on Play 2.0.4, and one repo that holds the shared database entities both apps use. What's the best way to get all that into one project in IntelliJ? All 3 items are git repos. I assume I only want to 'play idea' one of the Play apps, because that creates project files and I want all of these items inside one project not two?

Also what is the best way for that 'shared' repo with the ebean entities to be accessed by both apps, setup symlinks to the git repo into the app/ folder of both Play projects?

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.0, the sub-module support seems to have been replaced by using SBT's sub projects. More info on this feature can be found here: [SBTSubProjects](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTSubProjects)

The only downside to these is the restriction that you need to have the parent project contain the sub projects. You might be able to use symbolic links. Another option is to leverage git's sub-modules for the share component.

The other StackOverflow post contains more details on the approach using git's sub modules. Look for the accepted answer there: [Play! 2.0 framework multi Module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794500/play-2-0-framework-multi-module-project)