# Is it not possible to reuse shared code from Scala Play application without it being physically located within the same root directory?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I found the stackoverflow page 
[Play! 2.0 framework multi Module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794500/play-2-0-framework-multi-module-project)
when searching for information about how to structure the source code in a Play (Scala) project to be able to reuse code from another project.

In that stackoverflow page I found a code statement like this:

```
lazy val common = RootProject(file("../common"))
```

which looked promising, but then I also found the following comment:

*'Unfortunatelly submodules have to live under the project tree ("../core" as path isn't possible)'*

The comment above was from august 2012, and is the situation still the same or has something improved since then?

To me it seems very awkward and unnatural that you have to put shared code within the folder of a GUI-specific framework.

For example, let us say I want to create a Play application and a Swing application and want to reuse some shared code (in another project in a separate folder tree) from those two projects.

Then I would like to be able to have the three projects physically located in parallell directories rather than the Swing project using code located within a directory of a web application framework.

(Of course, I am now talking about debugging mode, i.e. when the source code is used, as in contrast to using jar file with the shared code since it then does not matter where the source code previously have been located when creating the jar file.)

I mean that I would like to see an example of how to use a directory with these three subdirectories:

rootDirectoryForSwingApplication

rootDirectoryForPlayApplication

rootDirectoryForSharedCode

(the Swing application is not really essential since my question is about how to configure Play, but I am just using it here as an example and trying to illustrate that I think it is strange to be forced to use common code within a certain web application framework)

Then from the Play application (somewhere within the directory 'rootDirectoryForPlayApplication') I would like to somehow use (and be able to debug from within Eclipse) the shared code with maybe a statement something like this if it would work:

```
'lazy val common = RootProject(file("../rootDirectoryForSharedCode"))'
```

(the point is that I want to somehow be able to use a relative path beginning with "..")

But as far as I understand this is impossible, or can someone please provide an example of what kind of code should be put in what file(s) to be able to use code in a "parallell" project (NOT SUB-project WITHIN Play application directory).

I realize you can share code the way I want by physically duplicating the source code in two places, i.e. with version control you can retrieve the shared code once into the location with the Play application directory, and then you can retrieve it into the directory you want to reuse it from another kind of application (e.g. a Swing application).

Though, I just do not understand why this limitation exists in Play (if it does as I believe).

Is it really that complicated (for the Play framework creators) to implement resolving a relative path beginning with two dots ?

I also can mention I have a C# and Visual Studio background, and in that environment it is very simple to put different kind of projects (e.g. Web applications and Windows Desktop Applications) physically parallell to each other without having to put reusable code within a web application project.

I really think this should be a trivial task to configure reusable projects and if the Scala/Play community would be interested in attracting more developers from the .NET  background it should be easier to do this kind of thing and there should be documentation with an example of the kind of configuration I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish the shared code to an ivy repository, in development this can just be your local ivy repository.  It doesn't make sense to have multiple projects responsible for building the shared code because it means if something about how that code is built changes, you have to update the build configurations of all the projects that share it.  It's also very bad practice to enforce a particular directory structure outside of a projects folder.  It makes things like fine grained CI impossible because you can only build if you also concurrently build all of the projects dependencies.  This is precisely why SBT disallows it.

So, if this is your shared libraries `build.sbt`:

```
organization := "com.example"

name := "my-shared-library"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Then run `play publish-local` on it, and then in all the projects that use it, add it as a library dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "my-shared-library" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: When you wrote "play publish-local" I suppose you meant "sbt publish-local" since the shared library is not supposed to be a Play application ?

Anyway, I marked your answer as accepted since you seem to be sure about it is an intended behaviour for SBT to disallow usage of a relative path as I wanted to do.

Comment: play is just a shell script that eventually invokes sbt, you can use it for ordinary sbt apps.  But there is a significant difference, the play script overrides the local ivy repository location, whereas vanilla sbt uses the one in ~/.ivy2.  This is important when you're doing publish local, to ensure you publish to the repository that your play app will see.